# php - what does this do $this->VARS_ = $vars;

Tags: php, arrays, content-management-system, var

I'm working on a wikka cms, and it has a main class and every action's parameter can be accessed inside the action through the arrat $vars['...'], I've found this piece of code on an existing costumization of the cms and What is it for what does VARS_ mean?

Comment: It sets a [class property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) called `$VARS_` with the value in the local variable `$vars`

Comment: so it can be used like this?

    echo $this->VARS_['..'];

Comment: Assuming that the value is an array, and that you're echoing from within the same class instance, yes